# How to trace which library is dynamically loaded

Tags: linux, executable, bin, objdump

Our system has an open source library. The tricky thing is we have 2 copies of the library, one is with our own modification and the other is the original. Both copies are in the source tree, but the customized one should be called at run time while the original one is used at build time for other purpose.

Now I suspect that during our system upgrade, the customization one got hidden from the original one. Because of the complexity of the system, it is doable but awkward to modify the source code in order to put in some trace. I am think if I could just objdump the top level library to get a clue.

Here are more details:

```
1) The customization one and the original one have the same source file names 
2) Their library names are same
3) The customization is some implementation change at deep within; so it is 
   invisible from outside
4) The 2 libraries are at different sub directory trees
```

Because it is dynamically linked, I actually doubt objdump can tell me any difference. But any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think ldd should tell you this simply, as a prediction rather than as a trace. For example for the ls command:

```
# ldd $(which ls)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00000333f2a54000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00000333f2610000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x00000333f2408000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x00000333f21f8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000333f1e48000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00000333f1c40000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00000333f19d8000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00000333f17b8000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000333f2838000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x00000333f15b0000)
```

For tracing you can abuse something like apparmor in complain mode for this.

Or use gdb, the GNU debugger. Example running the "ls" command:

```
# gdb ls
GNU gdb (GDB; openSUSE 13.1) 7.6.50.20130731-cvs
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-suse-linux".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.opensuse.org/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
..
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/ls...Missing separate debuginfo for /usr/bin/ls
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=eb844a5c20c70a59fc693cd1061f851fb7d046f4"
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) start
Function "main" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Temporary breakpoint 1 (main) pending.
Starting program: /usr/bin/ls 
warning: Cannot call inferior functions, Linux kernel PaX protection forbids return to non-executable pages!
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=afa98667969782208459e394f8c8f87ac7510710"
bak  core   learning.log       learning.mode  lr   old          test.log   testpolicy        testpolicy.large
c    learn  learning.log.uniq  ll             lrw  paxtest.log  test2.log  testpolicy.gradm  testpolicy.large.gradm
[Inferior 1 (process 25609) exited normally]
(gdb) info sharedlibrary
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00000342a0556ae0  0x00000342a056ee10  Yes (*)     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
(gdb)
```

Comment: the gdb solution is closest to what I am looking for. Question: after I step into the function, how do I know which library I am at?  "show sharedlib" does not work for me because many libraries are archived(or some other reason, anyway, I cannot see the library)

Comment: I don't know that much about gdb.   And BTW you can also use lsof, eg.    lsof -Pn | grep yourappname | grep "\.so"

Answer (score -1):

modify your classpath (if this is a java application) and add this customised jar prior to the one which was original.

this should solve the problem.

well sometimes the classpath used at the build time is saved and used during the runtime, but you can still modify this in your java's command line parameters for classpath entry, or if its getting run inside from tomcat you can still do the same.